# Hotjar mobile to record a programmatically trigger DOM click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, user-experience, hotjar

Since I am using a **canvas** on my website, what I want to attain is whenever I tap on the canvas, it would programmatically trigger a click event sample of code below

```
p.input.onTap.add(function(event) {


        var _myEvent = $.Event('click');
            _myEvent.clientX = event.pageX;
            _myEvent.clientY = event.pageY;
            console.log("TCL: _myEvent", _myEvent)

        $("canvas").trigger('click', _myEvent);

    }, this);

    $('canvas').on('click', function () {
        console.log('canvas is click programatically');
    });
```

By doing so, theoretically its like I created an action and hope that this trigger click event will also be recorded by **Hotjar**

If you had solve/solution to this problem would be a great help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens, does it work? the log is not catched?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#nameofID")[0].click();
```

or

```
setTimeout(function(){
        $("#nameofID").click();
    },1);
```

Remember that you should use jQuery('#nameofID')[0].click(); to issue a mouse click on current DOM element.
In some browsers a level 2 DOM .click() call can't work.

Comment: the problem now is there is no recorded coordinates